# Which quantity is bigger? (triangle inequality and ML-estimate)

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a piecewise smooth curve, $\gamma$ and a continuous function, $h(z)$ on $\gamma$ we have \begin{equation} \left|{\int_{\gamma}h(z)dz}\right| \leq  \int_{\gamma}|h(z)||dz| \ \ \ (\mathbb{a}) \end{equation} and if $\gamma$ has length $L$, and $|h(z)| \leq M$, then \begin{equation} \left|{\int_{\gamma}h(z)dz}\right| \leq  ML. \ \ \ (\mathbb{b}) \end{equation} However, I am wondering if you can, in general make a statement about which of $\int_{\gamma}|h(z)||dz|$, and $ML$ is bigger? My guess is that the order is $$ \int_{\gamma}|h(z)||dz| \leq ML, $$ since $ML = M \int_{\gamma} |dz| = \int_{\gamma} M|dz| \geq \int_{\gamma} |h(z)||dz|.$

I would love someone's thoughts on this. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, and your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you! I am quite new to MSE and have not before asked a question I was, from the beginning, correct on. Do you recommend me removing the question altogether or leaving it as is? 
Thank you again.

Comment: @iaenstrom General policy is never remove a good question, since someone else could come along with the same one. You are able to answer your own question and accept it if this occurs (feel free to do so).